# Creating all multi indices of given length

Tags: r, combinatorics

Given an integer `K` and a dimension `d`, how can I get all multi-indices `alpha` with `length(alpha) = d` and `sum(alpha) = K` in R?

Example: For `K=3` and `d=2` and if we organize the multi-indices in a list `alphas` we would get

```
alphas[[1]] = c(3,0)
alphas[[2]] = c(2,1)
alphas[[3]] = c(1,2)
alphas[[4]] = c(0,3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description, we may use `expand.grid` on the sequence from '0' to 'k', after `rep`licating the `list` 'd' times, then `Filter` only the rows having the `sum` as 'k'

```
f1 <- function(k, d) { 
 lapply(Filter(function(x) sum(x) == k, 
      asplit(expand.grid(rep(list(0:k), d)), 1)), unname)

}
```

-testing

```
> f1(3, 2)
[[1]]
[1] 3 0

[[2]]
[1] 2 1

[[3]]
[1] 1 2

[[4]]
[1] 0 3
```

---

Or slightly more faster would be to filter with `rowSums`

```
d1 <- expand.grid(rep(list(0:3), 2))
asplit(unname(d1)[rowSums(d1) == 3,], 1)
```

---

There is also a constraints based combinations functions in `RcppAlgos`

```
f2 <- function(k, d) {

 out <- RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(0:k, d, constraintFun = "sum", 
      comparisonFun = "==", limitConstraints = k)
 asplit(rbind(out, out[, ncol(out):1]), 1)

}
```

-testing

```
> f2(3, 2)
[[1]]
[1] 0 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 0

[[4]]
[1] 2 1
```

Or as @JosephWood mentioned `permuteGeneral` would be more adequate compared to `comboGeneral`

```
k <- 3
d <- 2
permuteGeneral(0:k, d, TRUE, constraintFun = "sum",
  comparisonFun = "==", limitConstraints = k)
```

Or with `compositions`

```
library(partitions)
asplit(compositions(k, d), 2)
```

Comment: `RcppAlgos` author here. As always, nice answer. I think this can be refined further as it appears we are looking for restricted integer compositions. For example, using the `partitions` package, we can concisely get the desired result calling `compositions(n, k)`, and using `RcppAlgos` we would call `permuteGeneral(0:n, k, TRUE, constraintFun = "sum", comparisonFun = "==", limitConstraints = n)`. I admit this is rather cumbersome, however it is very efficient (e.g. compare `n = 10` and `k = 6`). I should note `compositionsGeneral` (or something similar) will be in the next release.

Comment: @JosephWood thanks, I should have used `permuteGeneral`